# pull dollars out of a string of text

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var cats = "$22.50 + taxes";
var dogs = "4 Premium Plan Gifts for $150.00 + taxes";
var chat = "3 Forfait supérieur cadea... de 150,00 $ taxes en sus"
```

Initially I thought I was dealing with a consistent pattern in line with var cats. So I used this regex to return dollars: `cats.match(/^\$.*(?= \+)/);`

But it turns out the string will take several permutations and the only ting for sure that I know is that the number I want will either start with `$` or end with space dollar `' $'`

Is there a magic regex that I can use to return the dollar number?

Comment: [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/hpykuy59/1/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will search for digits or decimal separator either preceded by a dollar sign, or followed by a space and a dollar sign:

```
cats.match(/(\$[\d.,]+|[\d.,]+ \$)/);
```

https://regex101.com/r/lI1fB3/2

Comment: This is great. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you all numbers with leading / trailing $:

```
var data = '$22.50 + taxes ' + 
    '4 Premium Plan Gifts for $150.00 + taxes ' + 
    '3 Forfait supérieur cadea... de 150,00 $ taxes en sus';

console.log(data.match(/(\$[0-9,.]+|[0-9,.]+\s*\$)/g)); // ["$22.50", "$150.00", "150,00 $"]
```

Breakdown:

```
/ # regex start
  ( # capturing group start
    \$ # literal $
    [0-9,.]+ # 1 or more of the following characters "0", "1", .., "9", ",", "."
    | # or operator (meaning ether left hand side or right hand side needs to be true
    [0-9,.]+ # 1 or more of the following characters "0", "1", .., "9", ",", "."
    \s* # 0 or more spaces
    \$ # literal $
  ) # capturing group end
/ # regex end
g
```

If you want to remove the $ from the text you can use this:

```
console.log(data.replace(/(?:\$([0-9,.]+)|([0-9,.])+\s*\$)/g, "$1$2")); // 22.50 + taxes 4 Premium Plan Gifts for 150.00 + taxes 3 Forfait supérieur cadea... de 0 taxes en sus
```

Things to note:

```
(?:) # non capturing group (will not produce $1, $2, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
var cats = "$22.50 + taxes";
var dogs = "4 Premium Plan Gifts for $150.00 + taxes";
var chat = "3 Forfait supérieur cadea... de 150,00 $ taxes en sus";

console.log(  cats.replace(/\$\s*(\d+)/, "$1").replace(/(\d+)\s*\$/, "$1")  );
// out: 22.50 + taxes
console.log(  dogs.replace(/\$\s*(\d+)/, "$1").replace(/(\d+)\s*\$/, "$1")  );
// out: 4 Premium Plan Gifts for 150.00 + taxes
console.log(  chat.replace(/\$\s*(\d+)/, "$1").replace(/(\d+)\s*\$/, "$1")  );
// out: 3 Forfait supérieur cadea... de 150,00 taxes en sus
```

Or using only a single replace:

```
console.log(  chat.replace(/\$\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*\$/, "$1$2")  )
// out: 3 Forfait supérieur cadea... de 150,00 taxes en sus
```

Use 'g' if you want to replace all occurrences (the code above only replace the first one):

```
console.log(  (cats+" and "+dogs).replace(/\$\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*\$/g, "$1$2")  );
// out: 22.50 + taxes and 4 Premium Plan Gifts for 150.00 + taxes
```